Azure B2C Custom Policy - Output Claim 'RelyingPartyVpidList' not supported in technical profile 'AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId'
TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml (relevant code)
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="RelyingPartyVpidList">
        <DisplayName>relying party required verification process ID list</DisplayName>
        <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>relying party required verification process ID list.</AdminHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
  </BuildingBlocks>

<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="RelyingPartyVpidList" />
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>

AgentSignin.xml
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>myb2cprod.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>

  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="AgentSignIn" />
    <Endpoints>
      <Endpoint Id="Token" UserJourneyReferenceId="RedeemRefreshToken" />
    </Endpoints>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="agentId"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="agentFirstName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="agentLastName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="RelyingPartyVpidList" PartnerClaimType="relyingPartyVpidList" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
PartnerClaimType="idp_access_token" /> -->
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>

Stumped as we deployed these policies with minor changes (TenantId) to our DEV environment and it's working perfectly.

I've not come across a native RelyingPartyVpidList claim in the B2C directory for user objects - Usually custom claims are stored as extensions_{customClaimName} - Do you have any documentation you can link in your question to help diagnose the issue?

We have a TechnicalProfile that makes a MS graph call to gather a few custom claims. "RelyingPartyVpidList" is one of these claims. For brevity I truncated the list to 1 for this post, although all the claims output from this TechnicalProfile fail with the not supported message.
